# Unable to set cookie from PHP called by ASP Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 object

Tags: php, cookies, vbscript, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

I'm calling a php script from an asp page. The problem is that the php script called in this way cannot set the cookie. Here are the 2 scripts:

**setcookie.asp**

```
<%
    Dim objXMLHTTP
    Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", "http://127.0.0.1/setcookie.php", False
    objXMLHTTP.Send
    if len(objXMLHTTP.responseText)>0 then response.write "Result: "&objXMLHTTP.responseText
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
%>
```

**setcookie.php**

```
<?php
setcookie('mycookie', '12345', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
echo 'ok';
?>
```

The two pages run under the same website, in the same folder. I tried with both "POST" and "GET" with no success. If I run the php directly, cookie is created.

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Where do you try to read the cookie?

Comment: @Andreas Directly from Firefox debugger

Comment: You are setting the cookie as a response to a XHR so the actual browser will never see it as everything happens server-side. For that to even remotely work, you would need to pull the cookie from the HTTP headers returned in the XHR response and then set a cookie in ASP which seems to make calling the PHP pointless in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using server side code to call your php script.  This means that the cookie will be created on the server, not on the user's machine.  Even if you're using a development server on your own machine your browser probably won't know where to look for the cookie if it hasn't set it. You need to use client side code to to call your php page, you could look for a Javascript/Ajax solution or you could use a zero size iframe.

Alternatively you could learn how to use Classic ASP to set cookies.

[Using Cookies in ASP](https://web.archive.org/web/20210327022054/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/051099-1.shtml)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My final goal is to make a Wordpress user logged by using an ASP script. I call the following functions: `wp_set_current_user($wp_user_id, $username); 
wp_set_auth_cookie($wp_user_id); 
do_action('wp_login', $username);` but unfortunately the second call doesn't work.

Comment: I don't really know wordpress but I'd imagine that when you log in, it sets a session variable rather than a cookie.  Classic ASP pages can't read PHP session variables, (or ASP.net session variables)